# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "OS" for text to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm getting

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "OS"
```

when i'm setting language to textToSpeech.

```
textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
```

This line is throwing error for French language.

Comment: @Thunder - I have to set dynamically for different countries. On some devices it is crashing

Comment: @Thunder both are same